# Issues converting numerical values to string values based on logical conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign numerical values to string, based on conditions with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

dfwind.loc[(dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 0) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 2),
             'windspeed - mph'] = '0 - <2'
dfwind.loc[(dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 2) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 4),
             'windspeed - mph'] = '2 - <4'
dfwind.loc[(dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 4) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 6),
             'windspeed - mph'] = '4 - <6'
```

When i run this line i have no problem:

```
dfwind.loc[(dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 0) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 2),
                 'windspeed - mph'] = '0 - <2'
```

But when i run the other ones i got an error message:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how this is possible -- the same error ought to happen on all three lines.

Comment: It doesn't. The dtype of `'windspeed - mph'` is numeric until the first assignment to string.

Comment: @HenryEcker Aha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first

```
dfwind.loc[(dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 0) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 2),
                 'windspeed - mph'] = '0 - <2'
```

The type of the column is now str since the column contains strings and columns are a single type. Which is why the `>=` operator no longer works with an int.

---

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)

dfwind = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 7, 10), columns=['windspeed - mph'])

print(dfwind)
```

```
   windspeed - mph
0                4
1                6
2                1
3                2
4                1
5                5
6                4
7                1
8                1
9                5
```

---

To modify the code as written store all the masks before the column type is changed:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)

dfwind = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 7, 10), columns=['windspeed - mph'])

# Store Masks
m1 = (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 0) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 2)
m2 = (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 2) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 4)
m3 = (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 4) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 6)

# Update Values and change column type
dfwind.loc[m1, 'windspeed - mph'] = '0 - <2'
dfwind.loc[m2, 'windspeed - mph'] = '2 - <4'
dfwind.loc[m3, 'windspeed - mph'] = '4 - <6'

print(dfwind)
```

`Output`:

```
  windspeed - mph
0          4 - <6
1               6
2          0 - <2
3          2 - <4
4          0 - <2
5          4 - <6
6          4 - <6
7          0 - <2
8          0 - <2
9          4 - <6
```

---

[np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy-select) could be used to do this as well:

```
# Create Cond List
conds = [(dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 0) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 2),
         (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 2) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 4),
         (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] >= 4) & (dfwind['windspeed - mph'] < 6)]

# Associated Values With Conds
values = ['0 - <2', '2 - <4', '4 - <6']

# Assign values to column
dfwind['windspeed - mph'] = np.select(conds, values,
                                      default=dfwind['windspeed - mph'])
```

---

Depending on what the goal is [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut) might also be useful here:

```
dfwind['windspeed - mph'] = pd.cut(dfwind['windspeed - mph'],
                                   bins=[0, 2, 4, 6, np.inf],
                                   labels=['0 - <2', '2 - <4', '4 - <6', '>=6'],
                                   right=False)
```

```
  windspeed - mph
0          4 - <6
1             >=6
2          0 - <2
3          2 - <4
4          0 - <2
5          4 - <6
6          4 - <6
7          0 - <2
8          0 - <2
9          4 - <6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut`,

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'windspeed - mph': np.random.randint(0,8,10)})

df['windspeed'] = pd.cut(df['windspeed - mph'], [0,2,4,6,np.inf], 
                               labels = ['0 - <2','2 - <4', '4 - <6', '>6'],
                               right = False)
```

Output:

```
   windspeed - mph windspeed
0                6        >6
1                5    4 - <6
2                6        >6
3                2    2 - <4
4                4    4 - <6
5                2    2 - <4
6                6        >6
7                1    0 - <2
8                3    2 - <4
9                2    2 - <4
1
​
```